# Why are SPSite's, SPWeb's and SPList's UserCustomActions empty when a custom action registered via a feature's elements.xml?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I made a feature that installs a custom action via an elements.xml file (installed and activated it in a SPWeb).

```
<CustomAction Id="ChangeBrowseTabTitle"
            Location="CommandUI.Ribbon" 
            RegistrationType="List"
            RegistrationId="100">
<CommandUIExtension>
  <CommandUIDefinitions>
    <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.ListItem.New.Controls._children">
      <Button Id="Ribbon.ListItem.New.RibbonTest"
              Alt="Test Button"
              Sequence="5"
              Command="Test_Button"
              LabelText="Import"
              Image32by32="~site/SiteAssets/EM.SharePoint.ImportList/fileimport32.png"
              Image16by16="~site/SiteAssets/EM.SharePoint.ImportList/fileimport16.png"
              TemplateAlias="o1" />
    </CommandUIDefinition>
  </CommandUIDefinitions>
  <CommandUIHandlers>
    <CommandUIHandler Command="Test_Button" CommandAction="javascript:alert('That's me!');" />
  </CommandUIHandlers>
</CommandUIExtension>
```

Then I ran a console app that checked all the

- SPSite.UserCustomActions
- SPWeb.UserCustomActions
- SPList.UserCustomActions

in a web, where I registered the custom action.

But all the UserCustomActions collections are empty .

Did anyone encounter such a magic?

(The test was made on SharePoint 2013 Foundation October'13 CU).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not magic. You can not see your custom action in any of these collections as your custom action is registered to list template (list template id = 100 - generic list) and not to particular list, web or site. If you want to gel all custom actions in your SharePoint check this [post](http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2011/05/13/displaying-the-list-of-custom-actions-and-custom-action-groups/) but is little bit tricky.